# I need a Row_number over partition to achieve this in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, window-functions

I have three columns
PID, AppNo and ProcessedDate
I need a query to update the AppNo in the format below

```
PID AppNo   ProcessedDate
11  1      09/30/2019 18:21
3   1      09/25/2019 08:37
3   2      09/25/2019 08:37
11  1      09/25/2019 08:39
11  2      09/25/2019 08:40
7   1      09/26/2019 14:19
7   2      09/26/2019 14:20
7   3      09/26/2019 14:22
2   1      09/26/2019 14:23
11  1      09/26/2019 14:23
11  2      09/26/2019 14:24
11  3      09/26/2019 14:24
3   1      09/26/2019 14:24
```

For now the AppNo column is null.

This is the sql that is not working

```
SELECT AppNo, ProcessedDate,pid
,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, ProcessedDate ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS rn
select * FROM table
```

[image]

Comment: why 1st row has AppNo 3 instead of 1?

Comment: Oh so sorry. I have updated it.

Comment: Where is the sample data and where is the expected results from the two? They are both the same

Comment: The result I want is AppNo, I am sure you understand the logic before you asked me to update the question. I need to update the table with the values in App No. The sample data on ground is Column 1 and 3. Column 2(AppNo) is null at the moment, but those values there are what I want to update the column with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking to update your original table. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE to rank records with groups having the same date (without time) and pid, ordered by date (with time) and then do the update on the fly:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        pid, 
        ProcessedDate, 
        AppNo, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, CAST(ProcessedDate AS DATE) ORDER BY ProcessedDate) rn 
    FROM mytable
)
UPDATE cte SET AppNo = rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8a54bd34520b0418bf905380ff0515e)**

Original data:

```
PID | AppNo | ProcessedDate   
--: | ----: | :---------------
 11 |  null | 09/30/2019 18:21
  3 |  null | 09/25/2019 08:37
  3 |  null | 09/25/2019 08:37
 11 |  null | 09/25/2019 08:39
 11 |  null | 09/25/2019 08:40
  7 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:19
  7 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:20
  7 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:22
  2 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:23
 11 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:23
 11 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:24
 11 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:24
  3 |  null | 09/26/2019 14:24
```

After running the query:

```
PID | AppNo | ProcessedDate   
--: | ----: | :---------------
 11 |     1 | 09/30/2019 18:21
  3 |     1 | 09/25/2019 08:37
  3 |     2 | 09/25/2019 08:37
 11 |     1 | 09/25/2019 08:39
 11 |     2 | 09/25/2019 08:40
  7 |     1 | 09/26/2019 14:19
  7 |     2 | 09/26/2019 14:20
  7 |     3 | 09/26/2019 14:22
  2 |     1 | 09/26/2019 14:23
 11 |     1 | 09/26/2019 14:23
 11 |     2 | 09/26/2019 14:24
 11 |     3 | 09/26/2019 14:24
  3 |     1 | 09/26/2019 14:24
```

Comment: Perfect Solution. You are a life saver. Any advice on how to make it dynamic and also reduce computation time for already update column, I mean can I use  ```not null for AppNo ``` then bundle the script in a stored procedure to execute when a null value is found. Maybe a trigger or something

Comment: @PeterGodfreyObike: yes you can add a  condition in the *outer* query to only update non-null values, like `UPDATE cte SET AppNo = rn WHERE AppNo IS NOT NULL`. Beware however that you need to keep numbering consistent (what happens if you need to change an already affected row number, eg if a `ProcessedDate` is updated ?).

Comment: Your perceived question is already an issue, so I had to remove the not null and use your initial script in the program. But I think it has in a way reduce query execution time but it is ok. As the table gets largers it will be a problem. I made it a stored procedure. I can tweak it anytime from remote location. Please if you have any other idea, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Query.

```
SELECT pid as ProjectID
  , Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, ProcessedDate ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS AppNo
  , ProcessedDate
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

convert `ProcessedDate` to date if row_number shouldn't consider time as:

```
 SELECT AppNo, ProcessedDate,pid
,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, convert (date,ProcessedDate) 
                   ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS rn
from @T
```

You can write an Update as:

```
with CTE as(
SELECT  ProcessedDate,pid
,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, convert (date,ProcessedDate) 
                   ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS rn
from Test
    )
    update CTE
    set AppNo = rn
```

and test the result as:

```
Select AppNo , 
       Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, convert (date,ProcessedDate) 
                         ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS rn,
       ProcessedDate,
       pid
from Test
```

[Sample code here..](https://rextester.com/DMVSV1299)

Comment: You have solved 80% of my problem as I can get exactly what is on the table in my live table. But now, how do I update it? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

you must use partition just with date part like this :

```
SELECT AppNo, ProcessedDate,pid
,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY pid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ProcessedDate, 111) ORDER BY ProcessedDate) AS rn
select * FROM table
```

Comment: you shouldn't change the data type of `DATE` to `varchar()` unless it is really required other than representational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if `ProcessedDate` is of type `DATETIME` you can just do

```
SELECT 
    pid, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY pid, convert(date, ProcessedDate) 
        ORDER BY pid, ProcessedDate
    ) AppNo,
    ProcessedDate
FROM table
```

if `ProcessedDate` is of type `VARCHAR` you can just do

```
;WITH
t as (
    SELECT  pid, convert(datetime, ProcessedDate, 120) ProcessedDate
    from table
)
SELECT 
    pid, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY pid, convert(date, ProcessedDate) 
        ORDER BY pid, ProcessedDate
    ) AppNo,
    ProcessedDate
FROM t
```